# Continue add items from array until end loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
var Object = {
        "id": "Siplus",
        "name":"Siplus",
        "icon":"forum"
      },
      {
        "id": "Recent",
        "name":"Recent Activities",
        "icon": "restore"
      },
      {
        "id": "jobList",
        "name":"Job List",
        "icon": "briefcase"
      },
      {
        "id": "Favourites",
        "name":"Favourites",
        "icon": "star"
      },
      {
        "id": "searchQuote",
        "name":"Search Quotes",
        "icon": "binoculars"
      },
      {
        "id": "orderStatus",
        "name":"Order Status",
        "icon": "clock"
      };
```

I have another array Like this

```
var array = [1,2,3];
```

I adding array values to object using this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    object[i].number = array[i];
  }
```

I am getting result like this:

```
var Object = {
            "id": "Siplus",
            "name":"Siplus",
            "icon":"forum",
            "number":1
          },
          {
            "id": "Recent",
            "name":"Recent Activities",
            "icon": "restore",
            "number":2
          },
          {
            "id": "jobList",
            "name":"Job List",
            "icon": "briefcase",
            "number":3
          },
          {
            "id": "Favourites",
            "name":"Favourites",
            "icon": "star",
            "number":undefined
          },
          {
            "id": "searchQuote",
            "name":"Search Quotes",
            "icon": "binoculars",
            "number":undefined
          },
          {
            "id": "orderStatus",
            "name":"Order Status",
            "icon": "clock",
            "number":undefined
          };
```

I wanted like this :

```
var Object = {
            "id": "Siplus",
            "name":"Siplus",
            "icon":"forum",
            "number":1
          },
          {
            "id": "Recent",
            "name":"Recent Activities",
            "icon": "restore",
            "number":2
          },
          {
            "id": "jobList",
            "name":"Job List",
            "icon": "briefcase",
            "number":3
          },
          {
            "id": "Favourites",
            "name":"Favourites",
            "icon": "star",
            "number":1
          },
          {
            "id": "searchQuote",
            "name":"Search Quotes",
            "icon": "binoculars",
            "number":2
          },
          {
            "id": "orderStatus",
            "name":"Order Status",
            "icon": "clock",
            "number":3
          };
```

Is their any way to get repeat the number instead of getting "undefined"

Please help me for this

Comment: Hi Vinu, I suggest you edit the question with valid arrays (they are missing `[` and `]`) and you can't use `Object` as it is a reserved keyword (use `object` with small `o`)...

Answer (score 2):

You could map your input objects by adding the right value from array thanks to the modulo calculus

```js
var data = [{
        "id": "Siplus",
        "name":"Siplus",
        "icon":"forum"
      },
      {
        "id": "Recent",
        "name":"Recent Activities",
        "icon": "restore"
      },
      {
        "id": "jobList",
        "name":"Job List",
        "icon": "briefcase"
      },
      {
        "id": "Favourites",
        "name":"Favourites",
        "icon": "star"
      },
      {
        "id": "searchQuote",
        "name":"Search Quotes",
        "icon": "binoculars"
      },
      {
        "id": "orderStatus",
        "name":"Order Status",
        "icon": "clock"
      }];
var array = [1,2,3];
res = data.map((x,i) => {
  x.number = array[i % array.length]
  return x;
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of `array` is 3 while that of object is more - a solution would be to use:

```
object[i].number = array[i % array.length];
```

See demo below:

```js
var object=[{"id":"Siplus","name":"Siplus","icon":"forum"},{"id":"Recent","name":"Recent Activities","icon":"restore"},{"id":"jobList","name":"Job List","icon":"briefcase"},{"id":"Favourites","name":"Favourites","icon":"star"},{"id":"searchQuote","name":"Search Quotes","icon":"binoculars"},{"id":"orderStatus","name":"Order Status","icon":"clock"}]

var array = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
  object[i].number = array[i % array.length];
}

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @VinuViswambharan could you please respond to the answers? :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use an additional var.

```
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    j++
    if(j > array.length){j=0}
    object[i].number = array[j];
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for support.. Its working.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrLength = array.length;
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < object.length; i++, j++) {
    if (i >= arrLength ) {
        j = 0;
    }
    object[i].number = array[j];
}
```

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary value to point to the numbers array like this:

```
var temp = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    object[i].number = array[temp];
    if(temp == array.length)
         temp = 0;
    else
         temp++;
}
```